# listview is not scrolling inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-relativelayout, scrollbars

Actually having two listviews with scrollbars, one of the listview is not scrolling it.
Below is the code of the **main.xml**

- Code

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Container"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sky2_bgr" >
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sky_2bgr" >
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sky_3bgr" >
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        align_parentTop="true"  >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity1_name"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="Friends Activity"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/contentlist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activity1_name"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textSize="10dip" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity2_name"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="News Feed"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/newslist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activity2_name"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textSize="10dip">
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TableRow>
```

- Image

[image]

Comment: Satheesh i didn't see any relative position under relative layout. Please check the relative layout basics.

Comment: please check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html and http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/ for better understandings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

<ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:overScrollMode="always" 
        android:isScrollContainer="true" 
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" 
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity1_name"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="Friends Activity"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/contentlist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activity1_name"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textSize="10dip" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:overScrollMode="always" 
        android:isScrollContainer="true" 
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" 
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity2_name"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:text="News Feed"
            android:textSize="10dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/newslist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activity2_name"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textSize="10dip">
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you had `android:scrollbars="horizontal"` in your second `ListView`.

Comment: Do you use Eclipse for this xml file? Because there are many invalid attributes in the file. For example, android:orientation="horizontal" is not available for RelativeLayout, so as android:layout_weight in the child and a lot more like position etc. If optimised, this whole layout should not have to be this nested.

Comment: LinearLayout is used for another purpose, jus to scroll images horizontally. I guess its not unrelated.

Comment: We are talking about the ListViews in the RelativeLayouts right?

Comment: Anyway, I recommend that you use Eclipse as an editor since it can provide suggestions/error alerts. Also, take a look at the documents provided by @AndroidCoader. XML files are different from Java files, Java errors will throw Exceptions/compile time errors, but XML files won't and they just behave strange at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

> Scrollview should be define first i think ...try it

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Gives the following error "ScrollView can host only one direct child" . Anyway the problem has fixed. thanks for the code man